# Use concordance to find hyphenated words

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I was able to get the expected output of [this book](http://victoria.lviv.ua/html/fl5/NaturalLanguageProcessingWithPython.pdf), page 4 "Searching Text". When I tried to apply it to my case I got `No matches` which was not my expected output. I think I'm not tokenizing at the proper level (word instead of character) but am unsure of how to correct that. Any suggestions? The output I want is every hyphen lined up vertically with its surrounding context.

```
>>> f = open('hyphen.txt')
>>> raw = f.read()
>>> import nltk
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
>>> text = nltk.Text(tokens)
>>> text.concordance("-")
No matches
>>> text
<Text: Fog Air-Flow Switch stuck off ? Bubble Tower...>
```

(Python 3.4.3)

**EDIT**

I think I'm close by using regular expressions but I don't know how to remove the `'NoneType'` objects. Any suggestions?

[image: regex]

The output I'd want to see would look like this:

```
                 Fog Air-Flow Switch stuck off?
      Bubble Tower Check-Valve stuck closed?
           Chamber Drain-Trap broken, dry, or missing?
         Chamber Exhaust-Vent blocked or restricted?
 etc.
```

It's okay if the context is wider than the sentence with the hyphen - all that matters to me is that the hyphens are lined up vertically with its surrounding context.

Comment: Your link is not pointing to a book but to a picture. Also, what do you want to see when you type `text.concordance("-")`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @Gijs. Fixed the link that got broken in a previous edit and added the output I'd want to see.

Comment: You can get rid of the None objects with a list comprehension `words = [s for s in re.split('\s|(-)', raw) if s]`.

Comment: @Elliot your comment got me 99% of the way there. For some reason `.concordance` does not like to show the context prior to the target token (my case: hyphen) if the prior tokens are less than a certain length. To see what I mean do `from nltk.book import *` followed by `text3.concordance("beginning")` and inspect the first line of output.

Comment: I realized my starting point of using concordance for this was shaky. `for s in sents: s.rjust(len(s)+24-s.rfind('-'))` works much better because it gives the exact output I'd want to see. However I know the hard-coded `24` is a bad practice. Hopefully someone can give a more flexible answer. `24` is the max s.rfind('-') for all of the sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change your code little bit.

```
import nltk
f = open("/path/to/file") //path of the file
raw = f.read()
text = nltk.Text(raw)
text.concordance("-")
```

Required Output:
[image: information concordance]